# How to kill the app in android by pressing a button

Tags: android, kill-process, ondestroy, onbackpressed

I was displaying a dialog screen with an EditText field, cancel and ok button in the MainActivity class in onCreate method as below

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("User Login");
alert.setMessage("Enter your email address");
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String email = input.getText().toString().trim();
                if (email == null || email.isEmpty())
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert_email = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alert_email.setTitle("Email Not Entered");
                    alert_email.setMessage("Please enter email.");
                    alert_email.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Intent start_mainactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(start_mainactivity);
                        }
                    });
                    alert_email.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    doSomething();
                }
            }
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
```

So from the above code what i was trying to do was displaying an EditText view field to collect email from user, if user entered email, the code will  continue necessary processing, but if user clicked `OK` without entering data to EditText, just displaying another dialog saying that `"Email not Entered"` with an OK button, here if user clicked `OK` then i was starting again the MainActivity class to collect email which was working fine. The problem was

When first the main activity was started and clicked on `Cancel` button the app will exit to home screen which was working as expected

When user clicked on `OK` button without entering data in which main activity class was started by displaying email, cancel and ok button, now when we clicked on `Cancel` button in this stage the app was unable to exit to home screen but instead opening the main activity screen again.

So how to kill the process directly when user clicked on `Cancel` button at any stage

### Edit

By the below suggestions i have edited the intent starting code to below and it worked

```
Intent start_mainactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);


start_mainactivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
start_mainactivity.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(start_mainactivity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use intent to go home screen

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try... 
    `finish();`

to exit from your activity. or you can also kill your app by using

```
System.exit(0)
```

or

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your button event add this:**

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that your activity is re-opened? Maybe it just never closed. Opening a second activity does not automatically mean that the current activity is closed. You will have to do that with `finish()`